# Multiple "common functions" repeated in different razor component

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly

I'm working on project who has a lot of common repeated functions in differents razor components doing same work. Like this.

```
    void TrySelect(clsCity item)
    {
        _isOpen = false;
        SelectedText = item.Nombre;
        SelectedValue = item.ID;
        objSearchHotel.SearchObject = item;
        this.StateHasChanged();
    }
```

[example files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KXfY3.png)

This function (and others) are used at least in 26 files. Im new into a pattern designs, it's possible to create a file as service and consume/inject that service with this "common functions" in every razor component that i need? Something like repository pattern?

i'm new on pattern designs, still learning and i can't understand at all

Comment: You can make a class that extends `ComponentBase` that implements your `TrySelect method`. You can then use `@inherits` in your components to get access to the method.

Comment: you should consider refactoring this to its own component/control based around 'Open' and 'Closed' (or not 'Open') states and `RenderFragment` as it relates to those sections -- but it really depends on what `_isOpen` is doing or signals.  I don't, however, see any need to inherit on such a component from what you've provided -- nor does it have anything to do with services or repository patterns.  This is all control state, and handling -- probably best implemented as passing delegate/event handlers (i.e., `OnOpen`, `OnClosed`.. or whatever not open entails).

Comment: I suggest to check ...TyrParse extensions ...
Some types in c# already using this extensions.
But the real problem seems like design problem. StateHasChanged() Method used. Dont do this for updating every thing becouse you want a magic happen. Will not.


Some answers forwards you to injection etc. that magical words will not solve also.

Base component inherit may be. Go with that way. I suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will try to give an example of how it works in the form of your own codes.
Firstly, you should create an interface as follows:

```
public interface IFoo
{
     public clsCity GetItem();
}
```

Now, you should create a service and inherit from above interface:

```
public class FooService:IFoo
{
    public clsCity GetItem()
    {
      return clsCity;
    }
}
```

You should register the interface and service in the startup as follows:

```
Services.AddScoped<IFoo,FooService>();
```

Finally, You can inject the FooService in any components as follows:

```
@inherits OwningComponentBase<IFoo>
.
.
<EditForm Model="clsCityModel">
  <InputSelect @bind-Value=clsCityModel.Id>
   clsCityModel.Nombre
  </InputSelect>
</EditForm>
.
.
@code
{
private IFoo fooService => Service;
private clsCity clsCityModel = new clsCity();
protected override void OnInitialized()
{
 base.OnInitialized();
 TrySelect();
}
void TrySelect()
  {
    _isOpen = false;
    clsCity clsCityModel = FooService.GetItem();               
  }
}
```

Comment: are you just describing how to define and inject a service?  How does this address the issue OP is having with code duplication of `TrySelect` in several page components?  I'm not familiar with `OwningComponentBase`, is that somehow relevant to addressing the issue of code duplication? (as opposed to doing `@inject IFoo fooService`)

Comment: `OwningComponentBase` is an approach that limits a service lifetime in Blazor apps is use of the OwningComponentBase type. OwningComponentBase is an abstract type derived from ComponentBase that creates a DI scope corresponding to the lifetime of the component. for more info you can refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-7.0#utility-base-component-classes-to-manage-a-di-scope

Answer (score 0):

So, I would not suggest creating a base `class` and then inherit its funcionalities. If doing so, it should be an `interface` at least.

The best way to solve your issue from my  point of view —- is to create a service too. You could create an app-scoped service that you can inject in any class you need.

1. Create an interface for the service
2. Create a service class inherited from the interface
3. Register the service
4. Inject it where you need
5. No more duplication

[Useful link with instructions](https://blazor-university.com/dependency-injection/injecting-dependencies-into-blazor-components/)

I hope it helps you!

Comment: this.StateHasChanged(); <<< How this will work ?